# How to close a purchase order after updating packingSlip with code

Tags: axapta, x++

How to close a purchase order after updating packingSlip with code?

I know that i can have different quantity in purchLine.receivedNow for every purchLine and i need to post a packing slip and close the purchase order no matter how many items are delivered.

I am trying to post a packingSlip via x++ in AX 2009 and it works fine.
However, I need to close the purchase order at the same time.

I basically need:

```
purchParmline.closed = true;
```

any ideas on how to implement this? I have searched and found a lot of different ways to post purchase orders but nothing that quite answers my question.

```
void postPackingSlip(purchId _purchId, num _packingSlipId)
{
    PurchFormLetter     PurchFormLetter;
    PurchTable          PurchTable;
    ;

    PurchTable = PurchTable::find(_purchId,true);

    purchFormLetter = purchFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::PackingSlip);
    PurchFormLetter.update(PurchTable, _packingSlipId , today(), PurchUpdate::ReceiveNow ,AccountOrder::None,NoYes::No,NoYes::No);
}
```

I also tried to do it this way but with no success

```
void postPackingSlipOld(purchId _purchId, num _packingSlipId)
{
    PurchFormLetter         purchFormLetter;
    PurchTable              purchTable;
    purchparmtable          purchParmtable;
    ParmId                  parmId;
    PurchLine               purchLine;
    purchparmline           purchparmline;     
    ;

      purchTable=PurchTable::find(_purchId);
      purchFormLetter = PurchFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::PackingSlip);
      purchFormLetter.createParmUpdate();
      purchParmtable = purchParmtable::find(_purchid, _packingSlipId);
      purchFormLetter.createParmTable(purchParmTable,purchTable);
      purchParmTable.Num = _packingSlipId;
      purchParmTable.insert();
      while select purchLine
          where purchLine.PurchId == purchTable.purchId
      {
          purchParmLine.ParmId = purchParmTable.ParmId;
          purchParmLine.InitFromPurchLine(purchLine);
          purchParmLine.ReceiveNow = PurchLine.PurchReceivedNow;
          purchParmLine.TableRefId = purchParmTable.TableRefId ;
          purchParmLine.closed = true;

          purchParmLine.setQty(DocumentStatus::PackingSlip,false, true);
          purchParmLine.setLineAmount();
          purchParmLine.insert();
      }
      purchFormLetter.proforma       (false);
      purchFormLetter.specQty        (PurchUpdate::ReceiveNow);
      purchFormLetter.transDate      (today());
      purchFormLetter.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little grey on what you're asking, but if it's for AX09 and you want to "close" the PO.  I think that's the same as going to the PO Line and doing `Functions>Deliver Remainder` and choosing `Cancel Quantity`.

If that's what you're wanting, I believe the logic in the `Cancel Quantity` is just:

```
PurchLine.RemainPurchPhysical = 0;
PurchLine.RemainInventPhysical = 0;
PurchLine.update();
```

And the `update()` takes care of changing the statuses.

Comment: Thanks for that Alex. It didn't work at first because i had to refresh the PurchTable to see the changes.